# Make a single table in mysql read-only

Tags: mysql

How can I make a single table in mysql read only for a user while he still has write access to other tables in the same db?

Additional info

- I have root access to the server
- Tables are MyISAM
- Server version is 5.0.51a-24+lenny2

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Revoke all previous privileges and then grant the specific new privileges:

```
REVOKE ALL ON db.table FROM user;
REVOKE ALL ON db.othertable FROM user;
GRANT SELECT ON db.table TO user;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON db.othertable TO user;
```

Comment: If this user already has "ALL PRIVILEGES" on this table should i revoke those and assign individual table privileges on each table or can i override the privileges on the single table with SELECT only?

Comment: @chris valid question. nevertheless, simply trying this yourself should be a matter of seconds ;)

Comment: True but i'm not really eager to try this on the live database and setting up a test database with the same data is not a matter of seconds :) I will test it tho, lets see how fast i can get a local mirror of the live db :)

Comment: You just need to duplicate table structure for this and insert a single row into table in question. No need to mirror entire database.

Comment: @ChrisR not to mention, having this simple question answered would come handy for other users googling this issue, including myself.

Comment: @Emil, yes, please answer that additional query by ChrisR.

Comment: @ChrisR, yes, you should first revoke all privileges with REVOKE ALL ON table FROM PUBLIC and then do a GRANT SELECT ON table TO [PUBLIC|user]

Answer (score 4):

You can make a single MyISAM table read only by compressing the table. Use `myisampack` on the command line to pack the table.

More info can be found in the MySQL Manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisampack.html