# How to stop inserting records in MySQL table when a limit is reached

Tags: php, mysql

Any help in statement in PHP/MySQL which limits when a certain number of records are achieved.

I tried this `$query = 'ALTER TABLE admin MAX_ROWS = 5';` but does not work. Still populates it

Comment: So, you want the table itself to just hold 5 rows or the insert to be limited to 5 rows at a time?

Comment: your question is hard to understand.  are you using an insert statement for all the rows? are there a series of inserts?  by more than one user?

Comment: Just one insert by one user. But i want to halt insertion at a point of 5 records

Answer (score 0):

I think you should control this via permissions. You can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861564/make-a-single-table-in-mysql-read-only) which discusses how to set permissions for a user so that your table is read-only, which would disallow further insertions.

Comment: How does making a table read-only for a user only allow for a certain number of rows to be inserted?

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this restriction would be to add a column that is a `FOREIGN KEY` to another table which has exactly 5 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE const5
( i TINYINT NOT NULL 
, PRIMARY KEY (i) 
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

INSERT INTO TABLE const5(i)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5) ;
```

and then:

```
ALTER TABLE admin
  ADD COLUMN i TINYINT NOT NULL
, ADD FOREIGN KEY (i) 
        REFERENCES const5(i) 
;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [MySQL trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).

You can use a hack to abort the insert operation when the condition isn't satisfied.

http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/

But I still think that the best choice is to keep the logic in PHP code, so you can validate your database rows using `count(*)` before commit your insert.

Comment: you cannot query yourself from within an insert trigger - if you try you will get exceptions.

Comment: He want's a max number of rows in his table, with a special condition. He can create a trigger in the table structure to validate it. Then the query will not populate anymore...

Comment: Please expand upon your answer. Saying "use a trigger" is not helpful.