# Is it possible to make a MySQL Database Table not to allow any Modification

Tags: mysql

I have a look up table that surely contains fixed data, {names of month, their short form, numerical value}. Since this table is never likely to be changed, is it possible to prevent Insert/Update/Delete on the Database layer, on this table.

I understand this may not be a  particularly useful feature, I am wondering anyway if this is possible at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a single table in mysql read-only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861564/make-a-single-table-in-mysql-read-only)

Comment: The concern isn't more on user specific. The analogy on programming would be to have a const modified that prevents modification. It doesn't have to be specific to an user.

Comment: Do you want to make the table read only for admin, too?

Comment: Yes, the content of it. Well, the admin may not super privileges, so it is not mandatory for admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use myisampack for this.  Packed tables are compressed and not alterable.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisampack.html

Comment: this is closer to what I want, though it accomplishes much more.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, assuming table does not change in the future is not correct. How long are you going to keep the stale data? How long is it going to be valid? Where else do you save the new additions?

Second thing, if you really want to lock the table for read-only.

A couple of ways:

- Enforce this constraint in the application level. This is the standard practice.
- Create a SELECT (privilege) only user and use this user in the application to query this table. Some use this. But you need to switch between users in the application accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant privileges to specific user accounts, like granting only 'select'.