# How can I make some tables read-only but allow users to create new ones?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on some data project with a few other collaborators.  Most are fairly new to SQL so have inquired if I can make the 'raw' data tables read-only so they aren't accidentally altered, how would I go about doing that?  Currently all users have `GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO 'user'@'%'` permissions, but I need to be a little more open.

There's a question about making a [single table read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861564/make-a-single-table-in-mysql-read-only), but it seems like it would deny users the ability to make other tables; or if they did, they couldn't do anything with them.  There doesn't seem to be (or I can't find) a 'deny' setting like in NTFS that overrides allow/GRANT; from what I read REVOKE is only the opposite of a prior GRANT, you can't "nest" them.

I was considering making a separate 'raw' database that would be SELECT-only so users could copy it into the 'workspace' database, but that seems a bit hacky and will eat up some semi-significant amount of space on my budget cloud server.  What's the proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT SELECT ON example.* to 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Give read only privilege.

```
GRANT CREATE ON example TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Give create table privilege.

Comment: In the absence of a GRANT INSERT, etc. permission on the table they create, is it basically pointless as it would always sit empty?

Comment: Yes. Without privileges granted in advanced, nothing can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single MyISAM table read only by compressing the table. Use `myisampack` on the command line to pack the table.

More info can be found in the MySQL Manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisampack.html