# Prevent Writes To MySQL Table For Specified Time

Tags: mysql

How would you prevent writes to a MySQL table for a specific amount of time? I understand `LOCK TABLES` would be able to do this, but just for the duration the of the connection. I would like to prevent writes to a table regardless if there is a current connection locking the table or not.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This solution may work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861564/make-a-single-table-in-mysql-read-only

Comment: @StephaneM I was wondering if there was another solution that would not involve `GRANT`s. Something more like a timer that would apply to all users.