# Laravel inserting entries into wrong tabel when the model actually refers to another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is really an incomprehensible one for me:
I have the following tables:

```
attendance_2020_2021
attendance_2021_2022
attendance_2022_2023
```

Among them, attendance_2022_2023 and attendance_2021_2022 have corresponding models ListAttendance and ListAttendanceLastYear and attendance_2020_2021 doesn't have any as that table is rarely used.

The problem is that when I try to insert a new entry into the attendance_2022_2023 using the following loop:

```
foreach ($members as $member) {
     $attendance = new ListAttendance();
     $attendance->attendance_sessions_id = $session->id;
     $attendance->members_id = $member;
     $attendance->attendance_status = $status;
     $attendance->save();
}
```

Normally, all of these entries should go to attendance_2022_2023 but I find that sometimes, all the entries in that for loop go to attendance_2020_2021 which is really incomprehensible.

I use telescope for debugging and I found that while the model being called is ListAttendance (for ex: App\Model\ListAttendance:8410857(8410857-> id of the new entry in the 2020_2021 table)) ,

while the insert query is like this

```
insert into
  `list_attendance_2020_2021` (
    `attendance_sessions_id`,
    `members_id`,
    `attendance_status`,
    `updated_at`,
    `created_at`
  )
values
  (
    159460,
    1447801,
    'P',
    '2022-06-06 15:00:43',
    '2022-06-06 15:00:43'
  )
```

I tried looking into my code and I am not calling this table anywhere

this is my attendance model:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: lrr18
 * Date: 06/10/18
 * Time: 9:30 AM
 */

namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class ListAttendance extends  Model
{
    protected $table = 'list_attendance_2022_2023';

    public function session() {
        return $this->belongsTo(---);
    }

    public function member() {
        return $this->belongsTo(---);
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't happen every time this particular function is called, but only sometimes and I could't find any pattern to this

Comment: Very impractical table naming. Why don't you save everything inside an `attendances` table and get data by year? Do you really want to adjust the table names every year?

Comment: agree with @brombeer. Still if you want to change name  use this command 'composer dump-autoload'

Comment: I agree with it being impractical but there are tens of millions of entries every year and we expect somewhere around a billion or more entries at a later time which make the table very bulky and things get problematic with tables being very big even with indices. And most of the older entries are very rarely used.

Comment: @yash your issue resolved ?

Comment: I don't believe this is a problem caused by the framework, there must be something severely wrong in the setup or similar. Old projects being live where that was a problem, or an old queue running on old code.

Comment: I agree with @mrhn, I would take a look at the infrastructure that it is deployed in and see how an old version might be getting called sometimes potentially

Comment: Nope, not resolved! this problem started somewhere around 3 months ago and we just recently noticed it. Prior to that there was no problem and this happened out of nowhere. The thing is the table is not being called anywhere in the program now i.e. either by query builder or by raw SQL. So, only eloquent could do that. but as i mentioned above, I clearly specified the name of the table in the Model.

Comment: What about making old tables read-only?  and when the system try to insert data in those old tables will log an error? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861564/make-a-single-table-in-mysql-read-only) there is a solution to achieve this with a single table.